# React API Context - Function does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I am using the context API to select rows and place them in an associative array.
It worked with local state but with context API it doesn't access my function in LinesContext.js.

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from "react";

export const LinesContext = createContext();

const LinesContextProvider = props => 
{
  const [lines, setLines] = useState();

  const clickLine = (e) => 
  {
    console.log(e.target.parentNode);
    if (e.target.parentNode.className.length > 0)
    {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.remove("lineClicked");
      delete lines[e.target.parentNode.id];
      console.log(lines);         
    }
    else 
    {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.add("lineClicked");
      lines[e.target.parentNode.id] = e.target.parentNode.id;
      console.log(lines);
    } 
  }

  return (
    <LinesContext.Provider value={clickLine, lines}>
      {props.children}
    </LinesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default LinesContextProvider;
```

I embed my entire app in App.js.

```
import './App.css';
import Connection from './Components/Connection/Connection';
import Window from './Components/Window/Window';
import CourriersListe from './Components/Courriers/Liste/CourriersListe';
import DestinatairesListe from './Components/Destinataires/Liste/DestinatairesListe';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import LinesContextProvider from './Context/LinesContext';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LinesContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route 
              path="/" element={<Window id="windowConnection" 
              title="Connexion" x="100px" y="100px" w="640px" h="480px" 
              main={<Connection destination="/courriers/liste" />} 
              status="Tout est OK." fullscreen={false}/>}
            />
            <Route path="/courriers/liste" element={<CourriersListe/>} />
            <Route path="/destinataires/liste" element={<DestinatairesListe />} />
          </Routes> 
        </Router>
      </LinesContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I'm calling this ClickLine function in Liste.js.
When clicking on a td, the function is supposed to be called and select / deselect the parent element, the tr, by matting it in color or not and by adding / removing it from an associative array.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import './Liste.css';
import Button from '../Button/Button';
import {LinesContext} from '../../Context/LinesContext';

function Liste(props) 
{
    const clickLine = useContext(LinesContext);
   
    const doubleClickLine = () =>
    {
        console.log("doubleClickLine"); 
    }

    return (
        <>
            <table className='tableList'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan={props.headers.length+1}>{props.title}</th> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {props.headers.map((header, h) =>
                            <th key={h}>{header}</th>                   
                        )}
                        <th>actions</th>  
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.records.map((record, r) =>
                        <tr key={r} id={props.table+"_"+record[0]}>
                            {props.columns.map((column, c) =>
                                <td key={c} onClick={clickLine} onDoubleClick={doubleClickLine}>{record[column]}</td>         
                            )}
                            <td>
                                {props.actions.map((action, a) =>     
                                    <Button key={a} id={`${props.table}_${action[0]}_${record[0]}`} 
                                    type={action[1]} value={action[2]} click={action[3]}/>             
                                )} 
                            </td>
                        </tr>                
                    )}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan={props.headers.length+1}>
                            {props.buttons.map((button, b) =>
                                <Button key={b} id={button[0]} type={button[1]} value={button[2]} click={button[3]}/>              
                            )}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default Liste;
```

Comment: I don't know what the old implementation looked like, but you aren't calling `setLines` anywhere in your `clickLine` function. You need to call `setLines` in order for the child component to rerender with the changes in your array. Also, you shouldn't directly mutated `lines`. Make a copy first before you start performing mutative operations (like `delete`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably this. `value` prop in the case of the provider is expecting one object/value to be passed once the context is accessed.

```js
<LinesContext.Provider value={clickLine, lines}>
```

Since, `{}` is syntax. You need another pair of brackets to pass in an object.

```js
<LinesContext.Provider value={{clickLine, lines}}>
```

Finally, when you call `useContext(LinesContext)` the return value will be whatever you passed in the `value` prop earlier which is `{ clickLine, lines }`. so adjust your code accordingly,

```js
const { clickLine, lines } = useContext(LinesContext)
```

in order to access the `clickLine` function as well as `lines` state properly.

Comment: Its works ! 
I also add {} in the initialization of my state.
``` const [lines, setLines] = useState({}); ```
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
<LinesContext.Provider value={clickLine, lines}>
```

You have two values separated with a comma in your `value` prop. In JavaScript, the result of the expression `a, b` is `b`. So you are effectively settings `value={lines}`.